# The lines of items of an invoice are showing only in the last page, not in everyone c# reportviewer

Tags: c#, list, report, reportviewer

I trying to print the invoices in my application and I having an issue and I can´t solve it.

I have two classes, one with the head objects (TAlbVentaCab) and other one with the lines of the products (TAlbVentaLin). I already paged all the documents, and it shows everything but the lines of the invoice are only shown on the last invoice.

This is the code I have to show the report:

```
        List<TRegistro> albaranes = Db.LeerDatosAListaRegistros(sqlAlbCab, null);

        foreach (TRegistro albaran in albaranes)
        {
            TAlbVentaCab cab = new TAlbVentaCab();
            cab.NumSerie = albaran["NUMSERIE"].ToString();
            cab.NumAlbaran = Convert.ToInt32(albaran["NUMALBARAN"]);

            cab.UrlImagenTransporte = "file:///" + albaran["IMAGEN_ALBARAN"].ToString().Replace("d:","T:");               
            List<TRegistro> lineasEsteAlbaran = Db.LeerDatosAListaRegistros(sqlAlbLin, null, cab.NumSerie, cab.NumAlbaran);
            List<TAlbVentaLin> lins = new List<TAlbVentaLin>();
            bool peligroso = false;

            foreach (TRegistro linea in lineasEsteAlbaran)
            {
                TAlbVentaLin lin = new TAlbVentaLin();
                lin.Sku = linea["SKU"].ToString();
                lin.Talla = linea["TALLA"].ToString();
                lin.Color = Convert.ToString(linea["COLOR"]);
                lin.Cantidad = Convert.ToInt32(linea["CANTIDAD"]);
                lin.DescripcionProducto = Convert.ToString(linea["DESCRIPCION"]);
                lin.ImporteLinea = Convert.ToDouble(linea["TOTAL"]);
                peligroso = peligroso || lin.Peligroso == "T"; //Guardamos el resultado a verdadero si una de las dos opciones del OR lo es.
                lins.Add(lin);
            }
            cab.ContienePeligrosos = peligroso ? "Contiene peligrosos" : "";            
            Albaranes.Add(cab);

            ///Mostrar datos en el reporte
            /////reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();

            ReportDataSource rds1 = new ReportDataSource("DataSetAlbaranesVenta", Albaranes);
            reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds1);

            ReportDataSource rds2 = new ReportDataSource("DataSetAlbaranesVentaLin", lins);                             
            reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds2);                             

            reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

Also, I´m not able to use the class as DataSource with one of the objects List of the lines class, the windows doesn´t show the List objects, only the ints, strings, etc...

Any idea?

THanks!

Comment: Can you add how your UI looks a like?

Comment: Is just the report viewer file .rdlc